# Efficiently write compressed values to stream

Tags: go, compression, codec

Currently, I'm trying to translate some compression algorithm from existing C code.

Encoding and decoding doesn't appear difficult to me. It's more about the serialization to and from a stream (be it a file or a socket).

The input is 12 bit and the compressed output is 7 bits. But writing something to a stream always involves writing entire 8 bits.

So as there is always 1 bit remaining for each value, does that mean I would have to buffer 7 bytes just to be able to write 8 values? Which would give the following bytes (whereas all 1s belong to the first value, all 2's to the second one, etc.)

```
11111112
22222233
33333444
44445555
55566666
66777777
78888888
```

The real codec or the language being used both don't really matter (actually: the codec is G.711 and the language is Golang). So maybe the `go`-Tag is inappropriate.

Any clue on this?

Comment: In go you can just implement whatever `io.Writer` you want, and keep an internal state of the byte buffer, and manage it however you want.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But the point isn't actually about go. I'd had this problem in every other language where a byte is the smallest unit to write information to a stream. The point of this question is about how to write "single bits" more or less efficiently.

Comment: Go doesn't do anything different from other languages, this is mostly an architecture restraint. Maybe you compress larger chunks more efficiently, e.g. 8 groups of 12bytes under your scheme would compress to 7bytes.

Comment: I don't understand though if you want to be bound by a standard stream interface or not, because you can always create your own that works on a bit level and not byte level.

Comment: The problem is obviously that you're encoding into a 7 bit word when data is base 2... You're either going to be wasting 12.5% of the space or you're going to have to do a bitwise operation everytime you want to read a value. The obvious solution is to not use a compression algorithm incongruous with the storage system.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: I agree. Tell that ITU-T which invented G.711 ;-) And it's rather about network than storage - which doesn't do any big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use binary shift operators to load seven bits at a time into a bit buffer, and whenever the bit buffer has eight bits, output that.  At the end, if there are any bits leftover, output a final byte with what's in the buffer.

So something like (don't know Go, but this should be close):

```
bits = 0
bitbuf = 0
... some loop ...
    ...make your seven bits ...
    bitbuf |= sevenbits << bits
    bits += 7
    if bits >= 8 {
        output(bitbuf & 0xff)
        bitbuf >>= 8;
        bits -= 8;
    }
...
if bits > 0 {
    output(bitbuf)
}
```